# Does Chrome's mobile emulator have a height difference from the iPhone simulator?

Tags: css, iphone, cordova, google-chrome, html-framework-7

I'm testing the layout of a PhoneGap app (using the Framework7 framework) in the Chrome mobile emulator (iPhone 6) and the Xcode iOS simulator.  However I can't match the vertical layout across both simulators.

The Chrome emulator has a CSS resolution of 375x627, which (I assume) equates to 750x1254 with the device's pixel ratio being '2'.

What I can't understand is that even with a 20 CSS pixel space at the top of the screen for the status bar (40 device pixels), why does the Chrome mobile emulator still fall short of the iPhone 6's native 1334 pixel height?

The Chrome emulator's height seems to be (627x2)+(20x2)=1294... 40 pixels shorter?  Am I reading the figures wrong, or is Chrome's iPhone 6 device profile incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome mobile emulator is for inspecting the html and css and it does not read any configuration.

In your config.xml you have a setting for the behavior of the statusbar:

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true">
```

If it is set to true, then your html body starts in the top of your screen and you have to add 20px padding to it, otherwise you have the statusbar in your content.

If it is set to false, then the body starts below the statusbar.